# linux + network scanner tool that discover Linux rhel machine

Tags: linux, bash, rhel, python

we have network lab range from 18.2.1.1 until 18.7.252.253 , and we want to capture only the Linux RHEL machines with version 7.x ( /etc/redhat-release ) , ( we have around 2870 machines and only 390 RHEL machines )

of coerce I can create bash/python/perl script for this task, but maybe we can get some tool that already exist somewhere that can do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nmap`. Something like this will get you a set of results that can be further filtered through `grep` to match for RedHat systems. Assuming they're switched on and running `ssh`, and that it identifies itself there, that is.

```
nmap -oG - -p 22 -sV 18.{2..7}.0.0/16 | grep '/open/'
```